Next Auth save data in Session
I am using next auth to authorise users on my website. I have a backend that gets data based on data saved in the next auth session. I use getServerSession to get the session data. I now need a way to store custom data to that session. Something like: saveSession(session, data). Is that possible? I tried to work with callbacks but don’t understand how next auth handles session.
This is my nextauth.js


export const authOptions = {
  providers: [
    GitHubProvider({
      clientId: process.env.GITHUB_ID,
      clientSecret: process.env.GITHUB_SECRET,
    }),
  ],
  pages: {
    error: "/error",
  },
  callbacks: {
    async jwt({ token, user, account }) {
      console.log("JWT callback called");
      return token;
    },

    session: async (session, id) => {
      if(!session){
        return;
      }

      return session;
      
    }
  },
}



This is my api/route.js code:


const  session = await getServerSession(req, res, authOptions);

//Save Session data
if (session) {
  console.log("has session");


  session.id= "test"; //want to set id;

  authOptions.callbacks.session(session, "ppeep");


} else {
  console.log("no session");
}



My expected api/route.js code:


const session = await getServerSession(req, res, authOptions);

console.log(session.id); //expected to log myvalue if its set

await updateSession({session: session, id: myvalue});



Thank you very much for your help.
